# RDLC [BC30451] 'Lookup' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: rdlc

am getting following error on RDLC. i try to use Lookup function  (to combine two datasets) in RDLC but it showing below error

Error : [BC30451] 'Lookup' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level